# Quarkus - problem image with Qute and mailer and set image file for template

Tags: java, image, quarkus

I have a problem when execute service, I have image in the next path `META-INF/resources/quarkus-logo.png`, I have next method example:

```
    @Inject
    Mailer mailer; 

    @GET
    @Path("/html")
    public void sendingHTML() {
        String body = "<strong>Hello!</strong>" + "\n" +
                "<p>Here is an image for you: <img id=\"quarkus-logo\" src=\"cid:my-image@quarkus.io\"/></p>" +
                "<p>Regards</p>";
        mailer.send(Mail.withHtml("example@gmail.com", "An email in HTML", body)
                .addInlineAttachment("quarkus-logo.png",
                        new File(String.valueOf(quarkus-logo.png"))),
                        "image/png", "<my-image@quarkus.io>"));
    }
```

but i have error:`io.vertx.core.file.FileSystemException: Unable to open file at path '/home/user/quarkus/email-api/quarkus-logo.png'`

I tried with `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("quarkus-logo.png")`, but wen jar compile, I had same error.

My class is into package test.quarkus.resource,  Does anyone know any other way?

Comment: Have you tried using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()getResourceAsStream("quarkus-logo.png")`?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, yes I tried but, y had similar error:  `io.vertx.core.file.FileSystemException: Unable to open file at path '/home/user/quarkus/email-api/null'` with path file `'quarkus-logo.png`' and `'/quarkus-logo.png'`